# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.common.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, hcatalog, kylin

I'm trying to build a cube on Kylin with Spark as engine type. The cluster contains the following tools:

OS image: 1.0-debian9

Apache Spark 2.4.4 (changed from 1.6.2)

Apache Hadoop 2.7.4

Apache Hive 1.2.1

I'm getting this error while building a cube:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hive.common.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.createShutdownHook(HiveClientCache.java:221)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.<init>(HiveClientCache.java:153)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.<init>(HiveClientCache.java:97)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveMetastoreClient(HCatUtil.java:553)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:104)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:88)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:95)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:51)
    at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.HiveMRInput$HiveTableInputFormat.configureJob(HiveMRInput.java:80)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctColumnsJob.setupMapper(FactDistinctColumnsJob.java:126)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctColumnsJob.run(FactDistinctColumnsJob.java:104)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.common.MapReduceExecutable.doWork(MapReduceExecutable.java:131)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:167)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.DefaultChainedExecutable.doWork(DefaultChainedExecutable.java:71)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:167)
    at org.apache.kylin.job.impl.threadpool.DefaultScheduler$JobRunner.run(DefaultScheduler.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked the hive and hadoop library jars directory to see if there are any redundant jars and I found two versions of every type of jar. For example: hive-common-1.2.1.jar and hive-common.jar.

I tried moving either of them to a different location and tried resuming the cube building process. But I got the same error. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Hive version to 2.1.0 and it worked for me. I decided to install this version of Hive by checking the [Kylin download](http://kylin.apache.org/download/) page and in turn going through other cloud platforms like AWS EMR and Microsoft Azure HDInsight for Kylin 2.6.4 release.

Thanks, @Igor Dvorzhak for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported use case for Dataproc, if you need to use Spark 2.4.4, then you should use Dataproc [1.4](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.4) or [1.5](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.5) instead of Dataproc 1.0 that comes with Spark 1.6.2.

Aside this, `ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V` method was [added in Hive 2.3.0](https://github.com/apache/hive/commit/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4), but Spark uses fork of the Hive 1.2.1, that's why you need to use Kylin version that supports Hive 1.2.1.

Regarding duplicate jars, version less `hive-common.jar` is not a duplicate, it's a symbolic link to the versioned `hive-common-1.2.1.jar`. You can verify this by listing it:

```sh
$ ls -al /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common.jar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov  9 09:20 /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common.jar -> hive-common-2.3.6.jar
```

Comment: @lgor Dvorzhak, thanks for your quick response.
Earlier, I used Dataproc 1.4 Debian image with these specifications:
Apache Spark:2.4.4, Apache Hive:2.3.6, Apache Hadoop:2.9.2
While building a cube with this, I got the error: NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.ProtoUtils.convertToProtoFormat
I found out the possible reason is the version of Hadoop used to compile the application (2.7) and the version of Hadoop (2.9) in the cluster are different.
This is why I went with Dataproc 1.0 yesterday which has Hadoop 2.7.4. Please suggest the right approach to use here.

Comment: How do you install Kylin? If you are compiling it, you need to override Hadoop, Yarn, Spark and Hive version in [Kylin Maven build](https://github.com/apache/kylin/blob/master/pom.xml#L68:L83) to match Dataproc-provided versions.